# How to find running sum over two columns in SQL

Tags: sql, select, amazon-redshift, window-functions, cumulative-sum

I have a table like this:

```
month region    value
4/1/20  eu-west-2   110
3/1/20  eu-west-2   30
2/1/20  eu-west-2   13
2/1/20  us-west-2   2
1/1/20  us-west-2   242
4/1/20  us-west-2   240
```

I want to find the cumulative sum for the column 'value' for each region each month. For eg: Using the above example answer should be:

```
month region cumulative_sum
4/1/20 eu-west-2  153
3/1/20 eu-west-2  43
2/1/20 eu-west-2  13
4/1/20 us-west-2  484
2/1/20 us-west-2  244
1/1/20 us-west-2  242
```

I'm able to successfully write a query when I'm only finding cumulative sum for each month, but it's not working when I add region to it:

```
select
month, sum(value) over (order by month rows unbounded preceding) as cumulative_sum
from table
```

but when I do:

```
  select
    month, region, sum(value) over (order by month,region rows unbounded preceding) as cumulative_sum
    from table
```

it's giving wrong results.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are quite close, except you are missing the `partition by`:

```
select month, region,
       sum(value) over (partition by region order by month rows unbounded preceding) as cumulative_sum
from table
```

Comment: Oops I just forgot about the partition clause. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that `month` is a column of a date-like datatype, you can do:

```
select
    month,
    region,
    sum(value) over(
        partition by region, date_trunc('month', month)
        order by month
    ) cumulative_sum
from mytable
```

The `partition by` clause of the window `sum()` puts together rows that belong to the same month and region. Everytime the region changes or a new month starts, the sum resets.